# Golang service running on Kubernetes (EKS) gets OOM killed (high RES memory value, low runtime.Memstats.Alloc value)

Tags: go, kubernetes, out-of-memory, pprof, heap-profiling

I have a Go service that I'm running in Kubernetes (AWS EKS). I'm observing that the RES memory grows to the max `resources.limits.memory` of 365Mi and gets OOMKilled by Kubernetes. The RES memory grows to whatever max value is set, I tried assigning up to **2GB** to the pod, but it's the same pattern, the process gets OOMKilled. It seems like Memory is not fully released to the OS, but the service GC shows a small memory footprint (`12->12->9 MB, 19 MB goal`)

## K8s config and env variables

For easier testing, I configured pods to have `365Mi`, since it was the same pattern with `2GB`. This is the k8s manifest resources configuration:

```
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 365Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 1000m
        memory: 365Mi
```

With the following Environment variables:

```
GOMEMLIMIT: '180MiB'
GOMAXPROCS: '2'
GODEBUG: 'gctrace=1'
GOGC: '50'
```

Initially, I didn't have `GOMEMLIMIT` but I read that it could help, so I set it with half of the memory limit of the pod, but it doesn't seem to help. I also had the default `GOGC`, so tried the value of 50, but doesn't seem to help.

## Garbage collection

GC logs before it gets killed show the following:

```
21:03:41.854 gc 1643 @80939.735s 0%: 0.060+2.4+0.002 ms clock, 0.12+1.1/1.4/0.57+0.005 ms cpu, 12->12->8 MB, 12 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 2 P
```

## Memstats

`runtime.mstats` show the following (added MB conversion manually for easier readability):

```
21:03:43.195 
{
  "Alloc":8922888 (8.9MB),
  "TotalAlloc":5646312096 (5.6GB),
  "Sys":28415240 (28.4MB),
  "HeapSys":18284544 (18.2MB),
  "HeapIdle":6414336 (6.4MB),
  "HeapReleased":3121152 (3.1MB),
  "HeapInuse":11870208 (11.8MB),
  "HeapObjects":24393,
  "MallocsObjects":43016155,
  "FreesObjects":42991762,
  "LiveObjects":24393,
  "PauseTotalNs":153890330,
  "NumGC":1643,
  "NumGoroutine":265
}
```

`Alloc` is 8.9MB, which matches the end 8MB in the gc log (12->12->8 MB).

Here's another log sample before and after the OOMKilled:

```
15:39:21.969  my-service gc 1709 @168600.017s 0%: 0.033+3.5+0.002 ms clock, 0.033+0/0.059/3.4+0.002 ms cpu, 12->12->9 MB, 19 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 1 P (forced)
15:39:23.947  my-service {"Alloc":10126368,"TotalAlloc":5661878296,"Sys":36803848,"HeapSys":26771456,"HeapIdle":13369344,"HeapReleased":13336576,"HeapObjects":42613,"MallocsObjects":35141353,"FreesObjects":35098740,"LiveObjects":42613,"PauseTotalNs":70123823,"NumGC":1709,"NumGoroutine":264}
15:40:23.948  my-service {"Alloc":14120360,"TotalAlloc":5665872288,"Sys":36803848,"HeapSys":26738688,"HeapIdle":10780672,"HeapReleased":10780672,"HeapObjects":73826,"MallocsObjects":35172566,"FreesObjects":35098740,"LiveObjects":73826,"PauseTotalNs":70123823,"NumGC":1709,"NumGoroutine":264}
15:41:16.861  my-service Killed
15:41:18.201  my-service gc 1 @0.015s 6%: 0.007+4.9+0.002 ms clock, 0.007+0.027/1.3/0+0.002 ms cpu, 3->4->2 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 1 P
```

## top

`kubectl top pod my-service-pod-56f7fcffbb-d8tdh` shows:

```
NAME                              CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
my-service-pod-56f7fcffbb-d8tdh   8m           344Mi
```

`top` shows:

```
top - 05:04:05 up 14 days,  8:05,  0 user,  load average: 1.78, 1.95, 1.89
Tasks:   4 total,   1 running,   3 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 13.2 us,  5.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.2 id,  0.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.6 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15801.5 total,   4087.7 free,   9661.0 used,   2460.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   6140.5 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
     11 guest     20   0 2315940 348884  10532 S   0.7   2.2   7:02.35 my-service
```

## pprof

`pprof` does't show anything out of the ordinary either, total Memory allocated is `7096.39kB`.

```
go tool pprof ~/Downloads/my-service-pod-56f7fcffbb-d8tdh.tar.gz
File: my-service
Type: inuse_space
Time: Feb 6, 2024 at 8:40pm (PST)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 7096.39kB, 100% of 7096.39kB total
Showing top 10 nodes out of 35
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    4104kB 57.83% 57.83%     4104kB 57.83%  github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/v5/statsd.newStatsdBuffer (inline)
  902.59kB 12.72% 70.55%   902.59kB 12.72%  compress/flate.NewWriter (inline)
  553.04kB  7.79% 78.34%   553.04kB  7.79%  gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1/ddtrace/tracer.newConcentrator
  512.34kB  7.22% 85.56%   512.34kB  7.22%  crypto/x509.map.init.0
  512.31kB  7.22% 92.78%   512.31kB  7.22%  vendor/golang.org/x/net/http/httpguts.map.init.0
  512.10kB  7.22%   100%   512.10kB  7.22%  github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints.init
         0     0%   100%   902.59kB 12.72%  bufio.(*Writer).Flush
         0     0%   100%   902.59kB 12.72%  compress/gzip.(*Writer).Write
         0     0%   100%   512.34kB  7.22%  crypto/x509.init
         0     0%   100%     4104kB 57.83%  github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/v5/statsd.(*bufferPool).addNewBuffer
(pprof)
```

## Question

Am I correct concluding that there's no memory leak because of the following:

1. `runtime.MemStats.Sys` is low
2. `runtime.Memstats.NumGC` is constant (no unfinished go routines)
3. `runtime.Memstats.TotalAlloc` is big since it's the *accumulated* number since the service started but most of that memory has been released.
4. gc has very little memory to release each run (12->12->8 MB, 12 MB goal). I haven't seen that goal above 18 MB.

It looks like the gc is releasing memory but not all of it is going back to the OS. `runtime.Memstats.TotalAlloc` does show 5.6GB which tells me that *some* memory is released, the service keeps the max memory allocated in `resources.limits.memory`.

### References

These are some of the posts I found that sounded similar to my problem. A couple of them point to using `GODEBUG=madvdontneed=1` but I understand that is the default in Go 1.21

Related posts that look similar to what I'm seeing:

- [Top RES is showing more memory usage than the golang pprof-heap/runtime.MemStats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76903823/top-res-is-showing-more-memory-usage-than-the-golang-pprof-heap-runtime-memstats)
- [High RSS and OOM kill despite low value in runtime.MemStats.Sys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613683/high-rss-and-oom-kill-despite-low-value-in-runtime-memstats-sys?rq=2)
- [Why Golang MADV_FREE leads to OOM sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358183/why-golang-madv-free-leads-to-oom-sometimes)

Answer (score 2):

The culprit turned out to be that we were building the binary with `-race` in our Dockerfile:

```
RUN go build -race -v
```

As soon as we removed the flag, the Resident Memory Size (RES) dropped significantly! From `137MB` to `22.4MB` as seen on this screenshot:

[image: container_memory_max_usage_bytes]

The reason why this was hard to diagnose was that when using the `-race` flag, apparently there are some C libraries that the program will use and that memory is added to the Go process but it is not part of GC logs or `runtime.Memstats`. So the memory seemed unaccounted for from Go's perspective and that memory is not freed Go's GC.

We also ended up changing the Docker Image to Alpine to have a smaller image size (from 1.19GB to 535MB) which is unrelated to the memory footprint, but putting it here since it's a good practice anyways. Now we have:

```
FROM golang:1.22.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build -v

EXPOSE 8080

USER guest

CMD /app/my-service
```

See the following image of what RES memory would look like throughout weeks ending up in OOM pod restarts:

[image: Service running on EKS Kubernetes]

Chasing this issue, we also realized we could run fine with GOMAXPROCS=1 and less cpu. See [Bill Kennedy's article](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2024/02/kubernetes-cpu-limits-go.html) for more details on CPU limit. So now we have:

```
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 100Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 100Mi
    env:
      open:
        GOMEMLIMIT: '100MiB'
        GOMAXPROCS: '1'
```